# Property 'datetimepicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: angular, typescript

How to use `eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker` library with angular 6? I would like to setup default options.

Here is the link to the library: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

Here is the code:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
   ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor() {

    $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.keepInvalid = true;
    $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.useStrict = true;

    $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.useCurrent = false;
    $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.format = "MM/DD/YYYY";
    $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.keyBinds["delete"] = null;

    $.fn.datetimepicker.defaults.icons = {
      time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
      date: 'fa fa-calendar',
      up: 'fa fa-angle-up',
      down: 'fa fa-angle-down',
      previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
      next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
      today: 'glyphicon glyphicon-screenshot',
      clear: 'fa fa-trash-o',
      close: 'fa fa-window-close'
    }
  }

}
```

I get the following error

```
Property 'datetimepicker' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'
```

Answer (score 3):

I am late to the game, but the answer is to add the [@types/jquery.ui.datetimepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery.ui.datetimepicker) package to your project.  Since I use yarn, I did

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue for using eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker in Angular 6 Typescript project recently, hope my answer is not too late for you.

Okay, firstly I assume that you have installed/having the js & css script for it. These are the steps to overcome.

1. Firstly,

> Property 'datetimepicker' does not exist on type
>   '`JQuery<HTMLElement>`'

This is due to @types/jquery doesn't contain this `datetimepicker()` function, what you can do is **add datetimepicker function in JQuery interface in typings.d.ts**

```
interface JQuery {
datetimepicker(...any): any; }
```

[image: Add datetimepicker in JQuery interface]

2. Next, you need to include js and css file into the project. For my case, I include these 2 files by adding their file path into angular.json. For example:

   ```
   styles: [
       "your other css path location",
       "YOUR EONASDAN-BOOTSTRAP-DATETIMEPICKER FOLDER LOCATION/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"
   ]

   scripts: [
       "your other js path location", 
       "YOUR EONASDAN-BOOTSTRAP-DATETIMEPICKER FOLDER LOCATION/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"
   ]
   ```
3. Lastly, reload your project so it can take effect.

[image: Eonasdan-datetime-picker]